# How to Create Android Animated Vector Drawable

Tags: android, gif, lottie, fresco, animatedvectordrawable

I have https://lottiefiles.com/share/gordjiyb Lottie file for which I want to create Android Animated Vector Drawable,
We have used the Fresco library and converted the Lottie file into GIF in the drawable folder, which is taking 600 kb space.
I am sure Animated Vector Drawable will be more space sufficient.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Ldz42dbUsQ0?t=251

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next

1. Create a file that it is a html

[image: HTML]

2. Import the file in the assets folder
3. Add an webview component in the view

[image]

4. Load the file in the component

   package com.example.myapplication

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.webkit.WebView

   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   val webview = findViewById(R.id.webview)
   webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")

   ```
   }
   ```

   }

[image: Load]

Answer (score 0):

create an animation inside the res/animator resource folder (create it if it doesn't exist) and let's call it `expand1` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:valueTo="0.5"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:valueTo="0.5"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
    </set>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:valueTo="1.5"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:valueTo="1.5"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

this will create an object animator that will in turn scale up and down an icon

then create 3 more `expand2` `expand3` `expand4`

on each one change the scaleX and scaleY to be from 0.5 to 1.5 , to 0.7 to 1.3 etc, according to how big your circles should be at minimum and maximum

then create your vector drawable (ic_sound.xml) like so:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <group
        android:name="icon">
        <path
            android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
            android:pathData=" draw the microphone icon here "/>
    </group>
    <group
        android:name="circle1">
        <path
            android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:fillAlpha="0.2"
            android:pathData=" draw the darkest circle here "/>
    </group>

     repeat three more times for circle2, circle3 and circle4 with different fillAlphas
</vector>
```

finally create a vector drawable like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sound">
    <target
        android:name="circle1"
        android:animation="@animator/expand1" />
    <target
        android:name="circle2"
        android:animation="@animator/expand2" />
    <target
        android:name="circle3"
        android:animation="@animator/expand3" />
    <target
        android:name="circle4"
        android:animation="@animator/expand4" />
</animated-vector>
```

what this does is that it tells the ic_sound vector, to apply an animator to each group , so circle1 will expand from 0.5 to 1.5 , circle 2 will expand from 0.7 to 1.3 and so on

you can play with the times (if you want the animation to last longer) how long it will play , the interpolators (to add an accelerate or decelerate effect) to make it look as you wish